# Firebase remove children from RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I need to remove child from Firebase after **onClick** from RecyclerView Adapter.

I have something like this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  holder.fromTextView.setText(my_data.get(position).getFromName());

  holder.fromTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference messageRef = database.getReference();
    final DatabaseReference mess = messageRef.child("notifications").child(toId.toString());

    mess.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //Code for delete?
        }
   }
  }
  
}
```

Firebase Database:
[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Llo.png)
Android RecyclerView:
[Android Recycler View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua3sc.png)

After click on item, I need to delete it from Firebase Database.
I need to delete only **one** child.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User removeValue method and add listener to know the status of the delete operation as shown below. For complete example http://www.zoftino.com/firebase-realtime-database-android-example#realtime-database-delete

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("notifications").child(toId.toString()).removeValue()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("Delete", "Notification has been deleted");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("Delete", "Notification couldn't be deleted");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: But it remove all childrens from parent. I need to remove only one on witch I click in RecyclerView adapter

Comment: That means you have one more layer in your hierarchy, pass id of the node that you want to delete messageRef.child("notifications").child(toId.toString()).child(whateveid).removeValue()

Answer (score 4):

**Recap:**

Suppose you have a Database reference responsible for fetching your entire list of items called: **mDatabase**,which you should have already innitialized:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
```

And in your activity main method:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

And fetching your Data as:

```
  mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("myitems").child(someKey);
```

Now that your data is displaying in your recycler view,at some point we will use our mDatabase to successfully delete an item below:

**In your ViewHolder:**

You have to first get a reference of the position of your item from your ViewHolder which is directly referencing the item from the database:

Assuming your Database reference is **itemRef**:

final DatabaseReference ** itemRef**

You would have to assign the database reference to the position of each item by using getRef:

```
final DatabaseReference itemRef = getRef(position);
```

And there after use the reference to your position and database reference and assign it to a String which you will use to get the unique key of your item:

```
final String myKey = itemRef.getKey();//you can name the myKey whatever you want.
```

finally we can access the key to delete an item:

In this example:Lets assume your delete button is:delBtn,and your ViewHolder is **GameViewHolder viewHolder as below**:

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameViewHolder viewHolder,int position,
@NonNull final Game model)
```

**Deleting an Item:**

In your ViewHolder/referencing the viewHolder...we set an o'clock listener on our button and use our database reference for all items to get the particular items position and remove the value:

```
viewHolder.delBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
mDatabase.child(myKey).removeValue();
```

Our Entire deleting item code would therefore look like this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public GameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
return new GameViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, viewGroup, false));}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameViewHolder viewHolder,int position,
@NonNull final Game model){
final DatabaseReference itemRef = getRef(position);              
final String myKey = itemRef.getKey();//you can name the myKey whatever you want.


 viewHolder.delBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
  mDatabase.child(myKey).removeValue();

                    }
                });
```

[More details from this blog](https://link.medium.com/AEp4g2HksU)

[Firebase Official Documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete a Firebase database record, you don't need to use a listener, you only need to use `removeValue()` method directly on the reference like this:

```
messageRef.child("notifications").child(toId.toString()).removeValue();
```

Comment: But it remove all childrens from parent. I need to remove only one on witch I click in RecyclerView adapter

Comment: What returns `toId.toString()`? Does not only return a single child?

Comment: Yes, it returns "7", but I need to remove after click in on ItemView only this child, under "7". because there is :7-Somethin1 AND 7-something2

Comment: Then simply chain another `child()` method that will contain the desired child.